# Redirect a port to a blocked port but with the filter to unlock it

Tags: mysql, iptables, port, filter

I have all ports with iptables dropped for security reasons, now i want to open a port which redirects the traffic to a blocked port, but it will open if the traffic comes to this port.

Let's see, i have a mysql port 3306 blocked from remote access via iptables, i want to create a secondary port with iptables where i redirect the traffic of this 3306 port to a random port. Now i'd like to unlock 3306 when all the packets come from this random port (eg 41020). Is it possible? Are there any ways to do that?

Comment: This sounds similar to the concept of port knocking - look it up and see if that fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very much like you want to use what was some-time-ago known as 'port knocking' (thankfully it seems to have been a short-lived fashion). I believe there is google-able software for that, now that you know what you need to do.

... I would suggest though that it would be better to use something like a VPN or a client-side SSL certificate (preferably with stunnel because MySQL doesn't do SSL very well).

Answer (score 0):

Just configure `mysql` to use port 41020 for networking while usual 3306 is still blocked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JennyD  Everything is possible if ports are blocked not only on port number basis but also on interface/direction conditions. But networking is already complex enough to tangle it with unwise solutions.

Comment: Of course it's possible to change the port. But it's not what the poster asked for, and you don't give any information as to why your solution is better or how it would be done. Thus, it's more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @JennyD People often want not what they need. It's easy to see that mysqld on the non-standard port behave exactly the same as config desired by TS. Keep it simple, yeah?

Comment: It may indeed be a better solution - but how will the poster know, if you won't explain your reasoning? As it stands, the answer is bad because it does not contain the background the poster would need in order to make an informed decision.